# What is the correct term for "fine words"?

Tags: terminology, wording-choice, word-coinage

Usually when writing poems or literature, the authors looks for words that can convey their ideas faithfully. The same thing happens to the readers, when suddenly they understand the problem so clear. Mostly they're already available in the language, but sometimes one need to create a new one. In my language that kind of words are called "fine words", but how would English call it? It's the same thing with technical terms in academic fields, but what is an equivalent term in poetry?

Comment: How would this question be unclear or not useful?

Comment: Looks like a single-word request for [English.se]

Comment: I know it's on-topic there, but isn't this also on-topic here?

Comment: Dunno, I haven't voted either way. Personally I'd rather not yet another recommendation-type be allowed, at least a) not if they're on-topic elsewhere or b) not without defining minimum standards like wherever else it's on-topic. But that would be a question  for [meta].

Comment: @Ooker Yes, we've been perfectly fine with [tag:terminology] questions like this before. It's true that this might also work at [elu.se], but that community has experts in the English language, whereas for a specialised term of art like this, it's really experts in literature that you're looking for. I think you posted this on the right site.

Comment: However ... I don't really understand what the concept is that you're describing. Surely using "words that can convey their ideas faithfully" is just *good, clear writing*? (Also, what is the language in which they're called "fine words"? Knowing what we're translating *from* could help us to find the right phrase in English.)

Comment: @Randal'Thor one example I know is the word [flower of evil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Fleurs_du_mal). The word should be viewed as excellent by the test of time. My language is Vietnamese, which calls it "từ đắt" (valuable words)

Comment: @Ooker phrase, not word, it seems

Comment: @muru I think it depends on the language. In Vietnamese it's a single word

Comment: @Ooker probably, but what you linked to seems to be a French phrase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible term is *mot juste*, which means (in English),

> the exactly right word or phrasing. [See Merrian-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mot%20juste).

I believe it also means the same thing in French. We generally use the French phrase in English because there's no good equivalent English word.

Comment: is it equivalent to "the right word"?

Comment: @Ooker: I think it's a little stronger than "the right word"; maybe "the perfect word".

Comment: so what is the difference between "mot juste" and "the perfect word"?

Comment: I don't think there's that much of a difference, except maybe in plural where *"mots justes"* would mean more than one "*mot juste*", whereas "perfect words" would mean an exactly right phrase.

Comment: [As the old joke goes: you can always rely on English for the *mot juste*.](https://books.google.co.uk/books?isbn=8026083601)

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the creation of a completely new word, "neologism" ([a new word, usage, or expression](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/neologism)) might be what you're looking for. However, neologism doesn't have a value judgement associated with it: a neologism could be good or bad.